# Anonymous array with foreach loop in PHP

Tags: php

I was wondering how PHP handles an anonymous array, if I make use of it like this:

```
foreach(array('a', 'b') as $foo) {
    // ...
}
```

This wouldn't work if the array gets recreated on every step - but it works, so it looks like PHP creates a variable for that array (or something similar, doesn't really matter) - meaning this wouldn't actually have a bad perfomance. But is there any point why not to use anonymous arrays with foreach loops? (it kinda "looks wrong/bad" to me)

Comment: Not an anwer to your question, but this code bugs me too :P. I would use array-map (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) for this, just to avoid the look :P

Comment: I think the best example for anonymous arrays in `foreach` is: `foreach(range('a', 'z') as $char) {}`

Comment: "PHP creates a variable for that array (or something similar, doesn't really matter)" - it does, but that doesn't matter - you'd be creating one if you stored it in a named array as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a perfectly normal array, and such, should work.

Your terminology is quite weird, the term *anonymous* makes sense for functions, because normally the have names, but for arrays? Is an integer anonymous if you don't directly assign it to a variable? :) Nah..

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of that naming issue but couldn't think of a better (proper) adjective. Any suggestions?

Comment: My point is: no need for adjective because *nothing* special is going on. Really. Think about it. it's like `$x=1; $y=2; $z=$x+$y` vs `$z=1+2`. you don't wonder how you can directly write `2` there without assigning it to a variable. or `foreach (functionreturninganarray() as $foo)`...

Comment: This is exactly what my question is about - if there is any difference. Didn't see it that clearly, thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: I understand @Niko's use of "anonymous". Would "literal array" be more appropriate?

Comment: For the record - I actually Googled "anonymous array php", looking for information relating to arrays without names (exactly as the OP asked about). So- although the terminology may seem strange to some, it does kind of make sense.

Answer (score 6):

I don't see a reason not to use this.

It doesn't matter whether you use a directly initialized array, or an array variable as an argument for `foreach`. They're both valid arguments and there is no reason to assume that an anonymous array is handled any differently.

From a code maintenance perspective, it's also perfectly clear what is being done here, so there are no legibility issues either.

Comment: By avoiding the use of a temporary array variable, you're also reducing pollution of the variable scope. It's a minor point but also a nice side effect.