# php - define a long array

Tags: arrays, coding-style

I have a country list array which are very long. Netbeans suggests a function should not longer than 20 lines. So I want to ask if I can write this function in a short and beatiful way. Thanks!

```
class CountryList {

    private static function getCountryArray() {
        return array(
            "AF" => "Afghanistan",
            "AL" => "Albania",
            "DZ" => "Algeria",
            "AS" => "American Samoa",
            "AD" => "Andorra",
            "AO" => "Angola",
            ...
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to store the contents of the array somewhere. The question here is where. Currently you use a function to return an anonymous array. But you could also make the list a private member in the CountryList class and simply return that member in the function. This way, the function is only a few lines long and the array will only be initialized once each time an object of the class is initialized. (I don't know if static or final exist in php, such mechanism would even be better). Eventually, your could also use a configuration file to contain the data and use the function to read that configuration file into an array.

Comment: Uhh... pardon me, what is [anonymous array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7702715/4721245)??

Comment: It's an array without name, initialized in-line.  It is a rembrant of my time dabbling in Java. Source: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/learning-java/1565927184/ch04s06.html ("Learning Java", Patrick Niemeyer, Jonathan Knudsen, Publisher: O'Reilly Media, Inc., ISBN: 1565927184)